# knowing functions and dataset available in a package without any manual and information (blackbox) R

Tags: r, function, load, installation, package

I have a package which is beta version, I do not have manual neither helppage have a manual.

using following command, I can say that the package is loaded in current session.

```
(.packages())
```

When I search

```
data()
```

I can not see any data associated with. Is that mean that there is no dataset associate with it ? How can I know whether there are any functions?

```
function() # do not work.
```

Comment: You can do `ls('package:thepackagename')` to see functions it has - not sure about datasets. e.g. `ls('package:MASS')`.

Comment: To list functions, you could try `lsf.str("package:stats")`. Replace `stats` with the package name.

Comment: If you have the source code I would say: Use the source Luke!

Comment: @PaulHiemstra I do not have source code I believe,,,just windows installation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To list all stuff,

`ls("package:MASS", all = TRUE)`

`all = TRUE` shows hidden objects (i.e., variable name beginning with ".")

To list all functions with formals,

`lsf.str("package:MASS", all = TRUE)`

To list all datasets with brief description

`data(package = "MASS")$results`

Just in case, to list all imports and exports of the namespace,

`getNamespaceInfo("MASS", "imports")`

Comment: s("package:mypackage", all = TRUE) returns character(0), it works for MASS, is this means that the package is empty !

Answer (score 2):

From the help page for ?data

```
try(data(package = "rpart") ) # list the data sets in the rpart package
```

And this is one of the reasons why the uses of the name 'data' is deprecated.

```
try(fortunes::fortune("dog") )
```

Comment: hahaha, +1 for the fortune, that made me laugh - I should get round to setting up my .Rprofile for one of these per session :)